# Postgres to_date() function returns wrong year

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I used a query:
`select to_date(substring('0303653597' from 0 for 7),'DDMMYY')`

Expected output: 1965-03-03
Actual output : 2065-03-03

When I give the string as 030370 or above it behaves correctly.
Whats wrong with the predefined function?
Can we use any other function to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you won't get a better answer than the one from @whites11, but you can try to fix it by parsing the strings and adding the century yourself:

```
WITH j (dt) AS (
  VALUES ('0303653597'),('0303701111'),('0510511111'),('0510051111')
)
SELECT
  CASE 
   WHEN substring(dt from 5 for 2)::int > '49' THEN
     to_date(substring(dt from 1 for 4) || '19' || substring(dt from 5 for 2), 'DDMMYYYY')
  ELSE 
     to_date(substring(dt from 1 for 4) || '20' || substring(dt from 5 for 2), 'DDMMYYYY')
  END
FROM j;

  to_date   
------------
 1965-03-03
 1970-03-03
 1951-10-05
 2005-10-05
```

Play with the case condition and see if it fits your needs.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d4688a607a3ce444f80393e83ca3d950)

Comment: why and how 49?

Comment: @ShubhroMukherjee it is a random number just to prove my point. It means, all two character years larger than 49 will become 19** and the others 20**. As I mentioned in the answer, play with this parameters to find the ones that suit your use case. There is no silver bullet in this case ;)

Comment: While writing the query within java as NamedNative or Native...its not working #jpa #namednativequery

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html):

> In to_timestamp and to_date, if the year format specification is less
> than four digits, e.g., YYY, and the supplied year is less than four
> digits, the year will be adjusted to be nearest to the year 2020,
> e.g., 95 becomes 1995.

in your case 2065 is closer to 2020 than 1965 and thus it defaults to 2065.

Comment: any way I can achieve that coz my string cannot change

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this problem heavy relies on the fact that you can guarantee your dates are starting after a certain year for which the two numbers representation doesn't overlap with the years passed in 2000 century so far.

E.g. if the earliest datapoint is in 1930 you'll know that anything with `YY` less than `30` needs to be considered `2000+` and anything `>30` needs to be considered `1900-1999`. If you have entries also for years like `1919` the above problem is not solvable because any date with `YY=[00-21]` can't be uniquely associated.

However, if you can state that your dates can't be bigger than **today's date** then a possible solution is to check if the extracted date is bigger than today, if so, add a '19` prefix to the year, like in the example below

```
with dt as (
  select '0303653597' dt_str
  union all
  select '1705213597' dt_str
  union all
  select '1805213597' dt_str
)
select
to_date(
substring(dt_str from 0 for 5) || 
case when
  to_date(substring(dt_str from 0 for 7),'DDMMYY' ) <= current_date
  then '20' 
  else '19' 
end
|| substring(dt_str from 5 for 2)
,'DDMMYY')
from dt;
```

For the 3 dates (`03/03/65`, `17/05/21` and `18/05/21`) as of today (`17/05/21`) the output will correctly be

```
  to_date   
------------
 1965-03-03
 2021-05-17
 1921-05-18
(3 rows)
```